# XPath for label and drop down combined

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to create an XPath that will allow me to verify if a row in a table where label is "X" has the correct drop down value.

The XPath for the label is

```
//*[@id="mainContent"]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[1]/b
```

The XPath for the drop down is

```
//*[@id="mainContent"]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]/select
```

**How can I modify these so I only need one XPath?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "X" label is unique:

```
//td[. = 'X']/following-sibling::td[1]/select
```

Or, you can retain some,

```
//*[@id="mainContent"]//td[. = 'X']/following-sibling::td[1]/select
```

or all,

```
//*[@id="mainContent"]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[1]/following-sibling::td[1]/select
```

of the original path as necessary to meet whatever generality/specificity is required given the data on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to kjhughes' answer, but I would use

```
//td[1][b = 'X']/../td[2]/select
```

`[b = 'X']` more closely matches what the OP asked, since the `td` could have other content besides the label (including whitespace-only nodes). And using `td[1]`/`td[2]` ensures that we use the first two columns, as the OP did.

Comment: It's hard to know how wide or narrow of a generality net to cast, but these are good considerations to point out.  (+1)

Comment: @kjhughes: Thanks for your comment. I agree, it's hard to know how much of that is necessary. And BTW I upvoted your answer as well.